# I am trying to execute this code in console - it was throwing this error message "expecting a semi-colon, found 'newAlloc.add"

Tags: apex

```
String strReleaseId = 'a0CR0000003Ayaa';
String approvedUltId = 'a0JR0000004bWUK'; //supposed to be rejected.
String titleId = 'a0HR0000006YLaj'; //Title ID

//Fetch RecordType
RecordType rt = [Select SobjectType, Name, Id From RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Ultimate__c' and Name = '2) Budget'];

//Get Release Information
Release__c r = [Select release_date_reached__c,Id,Name,OwnerId,Territory__c,
                Territory__r.Region__c,Stage_GreenLight__c,Stage_Budget__c,Stage_Pre_Release__c,
                Stage_Post_Release__c, Ultimate_Due_Date__c 
                from Release__c 
                where Id = :strReleaseId];

//Create Ultimate
Ultimate__c ult = new Ultimate__c();
ult.Ultimate_Date__c=System.today();
ult.OwnerId=r.OwnerId;
ult.Title_Id__c=titleId;
ult.Status__c='Draft';
ult.Release__c=r.Id;
ult.Territory__c=r.Territory__c;
ult.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;
insert ult;

//Clone Allocations and Insert
list<Allocation__c> newAlloc = new list<Allocation__c>();
list<Allocation__c> lstAlloc = [Select Type__c, Type__r.Name, Title__c, Territory__c, Stage__c, Release__c, 
                                        Amount__c, Amount_Low__c, Amount_High__c, Amount_Cons__c 
                                From Allocation__c WHERE Ultimate__c = :approvedUltId];
for(Allocation__c alloc : lstAlloc) {
    Allocation__c cloneAlloc = new Allocation__c();
    cloneAlloc.Type__c = alloc.Type__c;
    cloneAlloc.Title__c = alloc.Title__c;
    cloneAlloc.Release__c = alloc.Release__c;
    cloneAlloc.Amount__c = alloc.Amount__c; 
    cloneAlloc.Amount_Low__c = alloc.Amount_Low__c;  
    cloneAlloc.Amount_High__c = alloc.Amount_High__c;
    cloneAlloc.Ultimate__c = ult.Id;
    cloneAlloc.Stage__c = alloc.Stage__c
    newAlloc.add(cloneAlloc);  
}

if(newAlloc.size() > 0) {
    insert newAlloc;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So the message implies that a semi-colon is missing just before `newAlloc.add(cloneAlloc);` i.e. on the end of the `cloneAlloc.Stage__c = alloc.Stage__c statement` which a visual inspection shows it is.